# Is it Possible to set the path of crystal report file based on the selection using SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

I want crystal report to be execute based on the values selected from the table.
Actually I have 5 .rpt files for 5 different values.When i select a values from sql it has to map directly to the respective .rpt file.Is it possible to do it in SQL Query.

Comment: whats your purpose? why not fill the report directly based on your query? why do you have to map them?

Comment: report going to generated once i press post button. Is it possible to do it in a trigger?map to report directly once i press i post button

Comment: give me suggestion?whether it is possible view report using query in sql.